# EditText Xamarin Android keyboard not showing up

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Anyone has any clue what's the problem here? On the simulation and my device the keyboard shows fine when selecting an EditText, but on a specific device (Huawei lyo l01) it doesn't.

Things that have been tried:
- clear partition cache 
- clear keyboard cache 
- use a different keyboard (gboard and swiftkey)

None of these helped

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtScreenName"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
    <CheckBox
        android:text="A"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1" />
    <Button
        android:text="Add"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd" />
    <Button
        android:text="Remove"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnRemove" />
    <Button
        android:text="Save"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnSave" />
    <ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lvFollowers"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:contextClickable="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: may be you need to force to request focus try  <EditText...>
    <requestFocus /> 
</EditText>

Comment: Will try tomorrow, thanks so much. But could you explain why it is like this in some devices?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `focusable` and `focusableInTouchMode` from the EditTexts. `focusableInTouchMode` should be avoided unless you are developing a game. Have a look at [this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2008/12/touch-mode.html)